# Payment : Square Payment - Magento refund issue - Missing the required parameter $location_id

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway

I am using **square payment gateway**. Magento admin refund issue, error message :

> Could not refund payment: Missing the required parameter $location_id
>   when calling createRefund If the invoice was created offline, try
>   creating an offline creditmemo.

How to solve the issue?

Comment: I think the problem is not in the payment gateway. You may be using some custom module which is observing the creation of the credit memo. It is not able to find the $location_id attribute. Were you using any custom module which has been disabled or removed recently?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora How to solve my error? Is any way to debug?

Comment: As you suspect that error is due to payment method, try placing order using any offline payment method and then invoice, ship and return the order. If the problem still persists, it is not due to payment gateway. Get back here with what you found after this.

Comment: In my store there is no offline payment.

Comment: You can enable it from the backend for a few seconds

Comment: @MohitKumarArora I have placed order using bank transfer option, order placed, order invoiced and also shipped, then what i need to do?

Comment: Were you able to refund this time or not?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Order received by bank transfer method, so no option for online refund, and off line refund working good.

Comment: Sorry @zus, I have not tried an online refund yet.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @PalomaMartinez Contact square technical team with your log error, they will guide you.